# Does $VP \neq VNP$ imply $P \neq NP$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, algebraic-complexity, conditional-results, gct

As far as I understand, the geometric complexity theory program attempts to separate $VP \neq VNP$ by proving that the permament of a complex-valued matrix is much harder to compute than the determinant.

The question I had after skimming through the GCT Papers: Would this immediately imply $P \neq NP$, or is it merely a major step towards this goal?

Comment: AFAIK, the Zoo gives all the known information.
http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo:V#vnp

Comment: The monograph "Completeness and Reduction in Algebraic Complexity Theory" by Peter Bürgisser (math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/habil.ps) may give you a better idea about the question.

Comment: Just updating Michaël's URL: https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:V#vnp

Comment: Another update for the zoo link: https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:V#vnp

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'. No such implication is known. There are two main obstacles: Going from arithmetic circuit complexity to boolean complexity (VP≠VNP implies P/poly≠NP/poly) and then going from boolean circuit complexity (P/poly≠NP/poly) to uniform complexity (P≠NP). Neither of these steps is known. I believe that P/poly≠NP/poly implies VP≠VNP, however.

Comment: Your last sentence is true: if there is a field where VP=VNP then P/poly=NP/poly (follow the link in Cadilhac's comment).

Answer (score 25):

*Assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis* (GRH), the following quite strong connections are known between $ VP= VNP $ and the collapse of the polynomial hierarchy ($ {\rm PH}$):

> 1. If $ VP= VNP\,$ (over any field) then the polynomial hierarchy collapses to the second level;
> 2. If $ VP=VNP\,$ over a field of characteristic $ 0 $, then $ \rm{NC}^3/{\rm poly}={\rm P}/{\rm poly} = {\rm PH}/{\rm poly} $;
> 3. If $ VP=VNP\,$ over a field of finite characteristic $ p $, then $ \rm{NC}^2/{\rm poly}={\rm P}/{\rm poly} = {\rm PH}/{\rm poly} $.

These are results from: Peter Burgisser, "[Cook’s versus Valiant’s hypothesis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975%2899%2900183-8)",  Theor. Comp. Sci., 235:71–88,
2000.

See also: Burgisser, "[Completeness and Reduction in Algebraic Complexity Theory](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/habil.ps)", 1998.

Comment: I think you meant that $VP = VNP$ implies the collapse of the polynomial hierarchy, not that $VP \neq VNP$ implies this.

Comment: @IddoTzameret Would P=PSPACE or P=PP or BPP=PP imply VP=VNP?

Answer (score 16):

I can give you an informal reason for why the separation would not prove $P \ne NP$.

VP and VNP focus on algebraic functions which degree is bounded by a polynomial.  Notice that it is easy to compute in an algebraic function of exponential degree with a polynomial size algebraic circuit.

There is a well known[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0212043) depth reduction for algebraic circuits: any polynomial size algebraic circuit computing a polynomial of degree $d$ can be turned into an algebraic circuit of polynomial size and depth $O(\log d \log n)$.

You may think of $VP$ as an algebraic variant of $NC^2$, thus proving that $VP \ne VNP$ amounts to prove an algebraic non-uniform equivalent of $NC^2 \ne \# P$.  That would not rule out $P = NP$, at least not immediately.

**Disclaimer**: I can't access the paper right now and I don't remember if the reduction works in any field or just in finite ones.

[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0212043) L. G. Valiant, S. Skyum, S. Berkowitz, C. Rackoff. [Fast parallel computation of polynomials using few processors](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0212043). SIAM J. Comput. 12(4), pp. 641-644, 1983.

Comment: is it the algebraic non-uniform equivalent of $NC^2 \neq NP$ or $NC^2 \neq \# P$?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow: you are right, and I fixed it.  While $VNP$ is considered the moral equivalent of $NP$, it is in fact more close to the spirit of $\# P$.  In fact the share complete problems.

Comment: Valiant et al. result works for any field.