# intuition that VP=?VNP is (not?) connected to P=?NP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, big-picture, p-vs-np, arithmetic-circuits

recently there has been major progress into the VP=?VNP problem for algebraic circuits originated by Valiant, inspiring some optimistic outlook on its eventual or imminent resolution.[1]

> what is an outline/ overview of an intuition that VP=?VNP is connected or *not* (closely?) connected to the P=?NP problem?

am looking for "not complex" or "straightforward" sketches or constructions, not necessarily "rigorous".

[1] [Recent Progress on Arithmetic Circuit
Lower Bounds](http://bulletin.eatcs.org/index.php/beatcs/article/view/293/275) / Ramprasad Saptharishi, Bulletin of EATCS

> The field of arithmetic circuit complexity has lately seen a flurry of results.
>   Several of these results are centered homogeneous depth four circuits,
>   and come tantalizingly close to separating the algebraic analogue of
>   P from the algebraic analogue of NP.

[2] [Does $VP \neq VNP$ imply $P \neq NP$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/529/does-vp-neq-vnp-imply-p-neq-np)

Comment: Your question already seems to be addressed at the question you linked, see Massimo Lauria's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does $VP \neq VNP$ imply $P \neq NP$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/529/does-vp-neq-vnp-imply-p-neq-np)